# Unit sphere contains a line segment $[x,y]$, prove x and y are linearly independent.

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces

If the unit sphere of a normed space $X$ contains a line segment $[x, y]$, where $x, y ∈ X$ and $x ≠ y$ ,
then $x$ and $y$ are linearly dependent and $||x + y|| = ||x|| + ||y||$.

My attempt :
If suppose they are linearly independent then there exists c $\in$ s.t. $x = cy$, which gives us that $$1 = ||tx + (1-t)y|| = ||tx + (1-t)cx|| = ||x|||t+c-ct | = |t+c-ct |$$

so for t=0, $$|c|=1 $$ that is about it.
Can anyone give me further hints, thanks,

Comment: If you suppose that they are linearly independent then there exists NO $c$ such that $x = cy$.

Comment: Are you trying to prove them linearly dependent or linearly independent?

Comment: The statement is not true for arbitrary normed spaces.  For instance, taking $x = (1,0)$ and $y = (0,1)$ gives us a counterexample in $\Bbb R^2$ under the $1$-norm.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I couldn’t find this questions. Apologies.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. What if $x=0$?

Comment: It can't be zero, right, since it belongs to the unite sphere?